# Deleting file marked as read-only by owner

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions

I am trying to delete a file that I have accidentally marked as read-only by the owner. Whenever I try to delete it, it says `File Access Denied: You require permission from ****\** to make changes to this file`. The permissions are as follows:

[image]

If I click on `Change permissions`, the buttons to add/remove permissions are grayed out as well.

[image]

How can I delete this file? I have tried deleting it from Powershell with administrator access, but still no success.

Comment: have you tried changing the owner to your user?

Comment: @FrankThomas I just tried it and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @FrankThomas Can you please post this as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So from your image, the item in question is not inheriting any permissions, and has only explicit permissions for the OWNER. As it stands, even with administrator rights, you cannot change the permissions.

If you are an admin, there are a couple ways to address this, but the easiest by far is to use the windows gui to [take ownership of the item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/take-ownership-of-files-or-other-objects). Simply click the "Change" link button next to the Owner name in your images. Assign owner to yourself in order to gain access to the resource.

Even though the owner only has discretionary rights to read the object, being owner has additional [privledges, including the ability to edit any DACLs controlling access to the object](https://networkencyclopedia.com/owner-ntfs/). Using these new privileges, you can grant owner the rights necessary to delete the file, or allow any other access privileges you like, including setting inheritance.